# Bounds and position in entity component system

Tags: java, game-engine, entity-component-system

I am working on a game engine mostly using ECS (not pure ECS) and I've run into a problem.

Some entities will need a `Bounds` component (e.g. a component that has a `Rectangle` that represents position, width, and height). Like buttons.
Many entities also need a component that contains the position but not necessarily bounds.

How do I reconcile the overlap?

1) If an entity has both a `Bounds` component and a position component, there will be two positions. Not good

2) Entity only has `Bounds` component which inherits from position component. Ugly because I have to override the utility methods like `translate` from the position component and have it update the bounds object's position. Also then the entity won't have a position component, which is weird.

3) `Bounds` component just contains width and height. I don't like this because then I can't use things like a `Rectangle` class to represent the bounds.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for 3, with a requirement to have a `Transform` component if you have a `Bound` component and express the bounds in local frame.

Using a `Rectangle` with lower-left and upper-right corners would still make sense since the origin of the bounds are not always the same as the origin of the component.

Comment: Ok, so when for example a Bounds component is translated, that doesn't affect its transform? It could work. Thanks

Comment: No it's just translated in the entity's local frame. Not sure when this would make sense though, probably when animating ?

Your world-space bound is given by transforming the `Bound` component with the `Transform` component attached to the entity.